# Running terminal commands throug java

Tags: java, linux, terminal, command

I have to execute two commands in terminal from my java program. Here is the java code that I am using :

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Runterminal {

public static void main(String[] args) {

Process proc;
Process procRun; 
    String compileCommand = "aarch64-linux-g++ -std=c++14 hello.cpp";
    String runCommand = "aarch64-linux-objdump -d a.out";
try{

     proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(compileCommand);
 procRun = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(runCommand);
 // Read the output

    BufferedReader reader =  
          new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));

    String line = "";
    while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.print(line + "\n");
    }

    proc.waitFor();   

BufferedReader readero =  
          new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(procRun.getInputStream()));

    String lineo = "";
    while((lineo = readero.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.print(lineo + "\n");
    }

    procRun.waitFor();   
}
catch(Exception e)
{
  System.out.println("Exception occurred "+e);
    }

  }
}
```

My `hello.cpp` file is stored in the home directory. When I compile the java program it gets compiled but while running it it is throwing exception. Here's the output which I am getting :

```
Exception occurred java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "aarch64-
linux-g++": error=2, No such file or directory
```

Comment: store `hello.cpp` in same directory where your  .class file is located.

Comment: well this has solved the exception but I am unable to see the output. Is there anything i should do different because the second command should generate the output in terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace using following lines in your code,

```
String compileCommand = "g++ -std=c++14 hello.cpp";
String runCommand = "./a.out";
```

And keep the `.cpp` file in same directory where the `.class` file lies.