# Executing "$ aarch64-linux-objdump -d a.out' in terminal throug java

Tags: java, c++, linux, terminal

I have made a cross compiler using gcc. Now I want the compile and run commands to be executed in a terminal through java program. Here is the code that I am using for this :

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Runterminal {

public static void main(String[] args) {

Process proc;
Process procRun; 
String compileCommand = "aarch64-linux-g++ -std=c++14 test.cpp";
String runCommand = "aarch64-linux-objdump -d a.out";
try{

      proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(compileCommand);
      procRun = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(runCommand);
  // Read the output

BufferedReader reader =  
      new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));

String line = "";
while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.print(line + "\n");
}

proc.waitFor();   

BufferedReader readero =  
      new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(procRun.getInputStream()));

String lineo = "";
while((lineo = readero.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.print(lineo + "\n");
}

procRun.waitFor();   

}
 catch(Exception e)
 {

  System.out.println("Exception occurred "+e);
    }

   }
 }
```

Now my first command is executing since I could see the a.out file being generated. The second command should dump the memory contents of file and it should print in in terminal but I am not seeing any output. Can anyone tell where I am going wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Running terminal commands throug java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29690048/running-terminal-commands-throug-java)

Comment: I have tried that I am unable to see any output in the console.